# What defines the set of appenders that a Log4j version 1 logger "contains"?

Tags: log4j

I'm trying to read some Log4j v1 code in order to update it to Log4j v2, and I've found something I can't resolve from the documentation.

The issue is the [Logger.getAllAppenders()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#getAllAppenders()) method.  The documentation, linked, says that the method "Get[s] the appenders contained in this category as an Enumeration."  There is no definition of what it means for an appender to be "contained in" a category there, however, and I can't find a definition anywhere else in the documentation.  Thus, I'm unable to predict exactly what the method will return.

As precisely as possible, what defines the set of appenders that are "contained in" a category like a logger?  In particular, does a child logger contain appenders assigned to its parent?  Does a parent logger contain appenders assigned to its child?

Answers that explain the basis of your knowledge, like links to documentation that I missed, are especially appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For end-of-life software like Log4j 1.x, the best documentation is the source code (which will never change).

`Category.getAllAppenders()` returns the list of appenders **directly** linked to the given `Logger` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j1/blob/b7e9154128cd4ae1244c877a6fda8f834a0f2247/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/Category.java#L411)) and does not include the appenders of parent loggers. Hence it is a subset of the appenders that will be used by that logger.

Comment: I can't read that source code, so I'll take your word for it.  Thank you!